# AFNetworking and UIImageView updating threading issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, afnetworking

So I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCells and inside my custom cell I have a UIImageView in which I use AFNetworking category's to load the image:

```
NSString *imageURLString = [[object.image_ valueForKey:@"low_resolution"] valueForKey:@"url"];
    NSURLRequest *imageURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30];
    [self.imageView_ setImageWithURLRequest:imageURLRequest andAnimate:YES placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){

    }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"FAILED");
    }];
```

The issue is that, sometimes when you scroll down.. it seems there's a long delay until the image request is triggered. I am testing in a very good connection. Why is this happening?

I am not sure my self whether the image request is triggered at a later time or the response just gets back at a latter point. But what I am seeing is that initially when the app loads the images loads fine. As I scroll down then all of the images are white.. if I wait patiently enough for like 60 seconds, then it loads up.

Comment: until the image request is triggered, or until the requested image is transferred and your success block is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible explanation is that when you scroll down your list, you are sending out a lot of requests that `AFNetworking` executes in the background.

As you scroll down, the number of requests sent out grows, and they will be possibly served at the server side in FIFO order (it could also be that the server will not exceed a given bandwidth when transferring images to your app), so when you stop scrolling before you can see the current images displayed, you have to wait for a bunch of previous images to load.

This could explain why you have the delay. I would suggest to put and NSLog trace in your success handler and log the request url, so you can see what happens: inspect the flow of incoming images; see how long it takes for each image to be transferred.

In general, what you are trying to do should be no problem, that is why I am thinking to a server side issue triggered by the number of requests you send it.

Comment: FYI, the server is Instagram API's